# Amazon SES How To Track Individual Link Clicks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-simple-email-service

I just finished setting up Amazon SES (Simple Email Service).  It's fully connected to a domain that I own and working beautifully.  I'm sending messages using PHPmailer instead of their API.  I've been digging into their version of tracking, and have done my best to follow their documentation.  I set up configuration sets with CloudWatch as the destination.

This works perfectly.  The send, open, delivery, and click metrics all show up on CloudWatch.  When I set up the configuration set, I selected **"Use Amazon SES default domain"** under the question, **"Which domain do you want to use for open and click tracking?"**

The one thing I can't seem to figure out is how to track individual link clicks.  The data that comes over to CloudWatch is simply a total number of link clicks and does not seem to have the ability to show which links were clicked.

In the Amazon SES documentation it says to add the following `ses:tags='data:value;'` attribute to each link element contained in the body of an email message.  However, the documentation doesn't address where that data gets tracked.

I'm wondering if anyone has figured this out before and is willing to share what they did?

I'm also wondering if I needed to select **"Use your own subdomain"** under the question **"Which domain do you want to use for open and click tracking?"**.  I tried testing this option but, there is a lot more set up involved and I'm not really clear on the setup instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to add UTM params to the links in the email and track the clicks on your own site's analytics, i.e. "https://example.com?utm_content=email-cta-2", which you can then find in whatever analytics tool you are using.